# How to recursively update xml attribute values with php?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm writing a function to reset all attributes values to empty strings for a given xml file. Could someone help me fix up this function to perform the requested tasks? Thanks!

```
// reset all attribute values to NULL or ""
function resetAttributes($xml) {
    foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
        foreach($child->attributes() as $attr) {
            $attr = "";
        }
        resetAttributes($child);

    }
    return $xml;
}

$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);
resetAttributes($xml);
$xml->asXML($xmlFile);
```

---

// Revision with Michael Berkowski's solution!! Inner child's attributes are left untouched. Maybe this is because of my PHP version? See screenshots at the bottom for more details.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
$xmlString = <<<XMLSTR
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description attr='12345'>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
      <sub attr='99'>
        <subsub attr1='asdb'/>
        <subsub attr1='asdb' attr2='xss'/>
      </sub>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author  attr='54321' attr2='99999'>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price price='88888'>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
XMLSTR;

$xml = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new SimpleXMLIterator($xmlString), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
// Then just loop over it. The recursion will be automatic
foreach ($xml as $node) {
  foreach ($node->attributes() as $attr => $value) {
    // Set the attribute to an empty string the same way as in 
    // your recursive function...
    echo (string)$attr;
    $node->attributes()->$attr = '';
  }
}
// That's all, write out the XML.
echo '<pre>' . $xml->asXML() . '</pre>';
```

1. http://img42.com/l9tSg
2. http://img42.com/9b18L

Comment: You wish to set the attributes to an empty string, or to _remove_ them entirely from the output XML?

Comment: They need to be empty strings

Comment: Ok hang on. I had typed up an answer but deleted it pending your confirmation.  I'll undelete it.

Comment: What is your PHP version? I tested your code exactly as posted above in 5.5, 5.4.9, 5.3.19 on codepad.viper-7.com and it works on all three.

Comment: (only the first of those two images you posted works, btw)

Comment: Ops, the 2nd must have expired. The php version 5.1.x which is kinda old, I know, but I can't upgrade right now

Comment: SimpleXMLIterator and RecursiveIterator are available back to PHP 5.1 but for a version that old which doesn't seem to  be working (I can't even find an online tester to check against) you should probbaly target the recursive function instead of the fancy iterators.

Comment: Ok sure, recursive function worked. What I don't quite understand is why I didn't need return anything from the recursive function? Initially I thought I had to do $child = resetAttributes($child)... and also $xml = resetAttributes($xml)

Comment: No value needs to be returned because the function isn't expected to return a value. Internally, it loops over a finite number of children and modifies the attributes in place (objects pass by reference) and when that completes, the call is done so you can never enter an infinite loop (which is usually a danger with recursion). I'm still curious why your old PHP is failing though. If you have error reporting turned up, maybe you'll see some problems.

Comment: I see... so its just passing a pointer to the recursive function. And the function is taking action on the original xml tree (rather than making a copy of it)?

Comment: Yes that is what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are certainly on the right track with this and your recursion will work correctly, but when iterating the attributes you should use `$attr => $value` in the `foreach()` and specifically set the attribute by name using the dynamic property name `$child->attributes()->$attr`.  This might not be the only way to do it with a SimpleXMLElement, but it is easy and it works.

```
function resetAttributes($xml) {
    foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
        foreach($child->attributes() as $attr => $value) {
            // Call attributes() and identify the attribute by name
            // which you get from $attr in the iteration
            $child->attributes()->$attr = "";
        }
        // Recurse as you are doing...
        resetAttributes($child);
    }
    return $xml;
}

$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);
resetAttributes($xml);
$xml->asXML($xmlFile);
```

#### But we can do better using PHP's SPL iterators...

Ideally, you may do this [using a `RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php), since [`SimpleXMLIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmliterator.php) implements the `RecursiveIterator` interface.

```
// The SimpleXMLIterator constructor wants a string...
$xmlString = file_get_contents($xmlFile);
// Instantiate a new RecursiveIteratorIterator for SimpleXML
$xml = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new SimpleXMLIterator($xmlString), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
// Then just loop over it. The recursion will be automatic
foreach ($xml as $node) {
  foreach ($node->attributes() as $attr => $value) {
    // Set the attribute to an empty string the same way as in 
    // your recursive function...
    $node->attributes()->$attr = '';
  }
}
// That's all, write out the XML.
$xml->asXML($xmlFile);
```

Comment: Hello, I implemented your 2nd solution with the SimpleXMLIterator. However, the new changes isn't saved in the original $xml that is written into $xmlFile. Actually, I'm having the same problem with both solutions :(

Comment: @user2799603 It does work in my testing. Verify that your XML file is writable by the user (web server?) executing it so that you can actually overwrite its original contents, or write to a new file with a different name. To debug that it actually works, instead of writing the file, use `echo $xml->asXML();` to view the returned XML string (from the browser page source);

Comment: @user2799603 And here's the RecursiveIteratorIterator http://codepad.viper-7.com/YoMcPY  Turns out I needed the `SELF_FIRST` mode to remove attrs on the innermost nodes, added above

Comment: Hey Michael, I'm still having a little problem. Could you take a look at the additions I made to the post above? It'll better highlight the problems i'm having. Thanks!!